# Ruby Iterating through multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, recursion, multidimensional-array

I just wanna know if there are other good ways to solve problems like the following:

```
p   [1,[2,3,"hi",[[[[2,"ex","bye"]]]]]].count_type(String)
# => 3
```

So our goal is to count the types in a multidimensional Array but, as i said, problems like this, not just this problem. The general problem is that we get multidimensional Arrays and then we need to search for types or Arrays which have a minimum index of 2 or some other conditions. I am sorry for my bad language usage and hope you get the point.

I know that recursive methods work. But is there any other way with recursive or non recursive implementation?

I use the following:

```
  def count_type(type)
    counter = 0

    self.each { |elem|
      if elem.is_a?(type)
        counter +=1
      end

      if elem.is_a?(Array)
        counter += elem.method(type)
      end
    }
  end

  return counter
```

I know that the part with `elem.is_a?(type)` differs and depends on what you are asking for. 
I forgot to tell you that it is forbidden to use flatten and my goal is not adding a new method to class Array but to learn new ways to solve the above explained problems.

Comment: I had to fix your indenting there because it was extremely confusing what you were doing there. Now it's clear there's something odd going on. The method `method` shouldn't be used for this, though.

Comment: For just type check problems you can use this one liner. You don't need to over ride Array class `[1,[2,3,"hi",[[[[2,"ex","bye"]]]]]].flatten.select{|elem| elem.is_a?(String)}.count`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge Hashes and key gets both, old and new values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31296706/merge-hashes-and-key-gets-both-old-and-new-values)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try and make this more in line stylistically with the Ruby core functions especially if you're intending to add it to Array:

```
class Array
  def deep_count(*args, &block)
    count = self.count(*args, &block)

    each do |e|
      count += e.deep_count(*args, &block) if e.is_a?(Array)
    end

    count
  end
end

[1,[2,3,"hi",[[[[2,"ex","bye"]]]]]].deep_count {|v| v.is_a?(String)}
# => 3

[1,[2,3,"hi",[[[[2,"ex","bye"]]]]]].deep_count(2)
# => 2
```

**Update:** Version without patching core Array:

```
def array_deep_count(array, *args, &block)
  count = array.count(*args, &block)

  array.each do |e|
    count += e.deep_count(*args, &block) if e.is_a?(Array)
  end

  count
end
```

This largely involves swapping `self` with an argument.

Comment: Thanks! that was fast. thats  a bit too much for me XD. I just wrote class Array because i wanna use self and i thought i cant use self without it but i think i am wrong ^^. I just wanna know other or better ways to iterate through arrays

Comment: I think OP doesn't need the Array class override.

Comment: The second requirement was not number of 2's. Its Arrays which have a minimum index of 2.

Comment: For minimum length of 2: `[...].deep_count { |a| a.is_a?(Array) and a.length >= 2 }`

Comment: Can u show me the version without adding it to Array,pls? I do not understand your way. ^^

Comment: Added a procedural version.